# Returning the original value if it doesn't match any of the when_expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case-when

I have a line on my SQL export field, and I am trying to remove return a blank value in a field if it exactly matches "AMA" in the last name. However, when I export the file with the current code, and names without "AMA" as the last name are fully blanked out.

```
,Max(
    Orders.ShipFirstName
    + ' ' +  
        CASE Orders.ShipLastName
            WHEN 'AMA' THEN ''
        END
) As ShipFullName
```

Right now, if someone is "Ray Miller", `ShipFullName` will be returned as blank. But if their name is "Ray AMA", then their name is returned as "Ray". I want it so "Ray Miller" is returned when AMA is not found in the last name field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid having a trailing blank, I would do this:

```
max(
    case 
        when Orders.ShipLastName = 'AMA' then Orders.ShipFirstName
        else Orders.ShipFirstName + ' ' + Orders.ShipLastName
    end
) as ShipFullName
```

Comment: This is the only I ultimately used.

Comment: @JackCole: imo, such transformation should be done on the presentation layer, not the data access layer.

Comment: This is a shipping address export file, and for around a year I've had a batch file that the shippers run to fix this. But they would sometimes forget and ship stuff with "AMA" in the name. As for why it says "AMA" in the first place: the coder who made the file that imports from another database couldn't figure out how to parse a full name into separate fields, so he just made the entire name the fist name, and the last name "AMA". He wont let me touch his code so I have to fix the problems that arise from it this way.

Answer (score 6):

```
CASE Orders.ShipLastName
    WHEN 'AMA' THEN ''
    ELSE Orders.ShipLastName
END
```

Comment: Danke, I've been trying variations of this for a while but always got an error. Yours worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
,Max(
    Orders.ShipFirstName
    + ' ' +  IF(Orders.ShipLastName = 'AMA', '', Orders.ShipLastName)
) As ShipFullName
```