# SQL if/case statement - returning value from db

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have trouble with sql command in MS Sql server ..... 
I would like to  check names in table. in Column are e.g. Carl, Loius, Manfred, Jenny .... 
Is there any way, to create case or if statement :

```
Case  when name = 'Carl' then 'Man'
else Return original value(name) from table?
```

(Louis, Manfred, Jenny) ?

If yes, how can i achieve that ? Case statement? If statement? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning the original value if it doesn't match any of the when\_expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513751/returning-the-original-value-if-it-doesnt-match-any-of-the-when-expressions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
 select (Case when name = 'Carl' then 'Man' else name end)
```

Answer (score 3):

you mean something like this ?

```
select name,
       case when name = 'Carl' then 'Man' 
            when name = 'Jenny' then 'women'
       else name end
from   yourtable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  Select case when name in ('Carl','Manfred',....) 
   Then 'Man' else 'Women' end as gender 
    from your_table
```

Answer (score 2):

Another (shorter to write) option is to use nullif and isnull:

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(name, 'Carl'), name)) as name
FROM yourTable.
```

The `NULLIF` function will return null if both arguments are equale, and the `ISNULL` will return the first argument unless it's null - in that case it will return the second argument.